# scan inputs to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm a newbie of programming. I have wrote a function to scan inputs to linked list. But it does not work. Can anyone help me find what the problem is?

```
ListNode *BuildList() {
    char discard;
    ListNode *list,*list2=NULL;
    list = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    if ((scanf("%d%1[^\n]s", &list->val, &discard)) == 2) {
        list->next = BuildList();
        printf("%d ", list->next->val);
    }
    else
    {
        list->next = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```

and ListNode is defined as

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful problem statement. Please read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: 1) `"%d%1[^\n]s"` is wrong.

Comment: Try `if (scanf("%d", &list->val) == 1) { scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c"); …`

Comment: @CoolGuy The format of the input is unclear at this time.

Comment: The format of input is totally fine, it stops reading once it sees a newline(\n).

Answer (score 0):

I had to take your code and try to reproduce the errors you are getting.
Your code looks fine except that it gives compile-times errors as it fails to infer the type for `ListNode`.
Typical errors are I getting that I think you are:

```
test.c:11:5: error: unknown type name ‘ListNode’
     ListNode *list,*list2=NULL;
```

There are two solution alternatives:

*One*, modify the struct definition as below. With this approach, your code works like a charm.

```
typedef struct ListNode {
  int val;
  struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;
```

*Two*, retain the definition of your struct but precede every struct variable declaration with keyword `struct`. E.g; instead of `ListNode *list,*list2=NULL;` do `struct ListNode *list,*list2=NULL;`

I tried to run your code, the sample input, and produced output is below. I hope this is how you expect your function to behave.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 // <- input
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 // <- output
```